# Difference in time between current record and previous record (with a lag variable and case statement)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, case

I want to calculate the time between subsequent records in SQL if the records happened on the same day.

I have a table that looks like this with data from January 24th and 25th from the same piece of equipment:

EQUIPMENTNUMBER |   TimeOfDay   |   Month   |   WeekNumber  |   Day |   Year
10020576    |   4:18:58 AM  |   1   |   4   |   24  |   2019
10020576    |   4:57:23 AM  |   1   |   4   |   24  |   2019
10020576    |   3:22:47 AM  |   1   |   4   |   25  |   2019
10020576    |   4:19:14 AM  |   1   |   4   |   25  |   2019

I am able to use a lag variable within a case statement to identify if the previous record occured on the same day as the current record. Using the following code, I get the following table:

```
SELECT  
EQUIPMENTNUMBER,   
[TimeOfDay],   
Month,  
WeekNumber,  
Day,   
Year,  
CASE  
    WHEN Day = lag(day,1,0) over (order by EQUIPMENTNUMBER, YEAR, WeekNumber,  
 DAY,timeofday) 
THEN 1 
ELSE 0   
END as [PreviousRecordOnSameDay]  
FROM [Table]
```

EQUIPMENTNUMBER |   TimeOfDay   |   Month   |   WeekNumber  |   Day |   Year    |   PreviousRecordOnSameDay
10020576    |   4:18:58 AM  |   1   |   4   |   24  |   2019    |   0
10020576    |   4:57:23 AM  |   1   |   4   |   24  |   2019    |   1
10020576    |   3:22:47 AM  |   1   |   4   |   25  |   2019    |   0
10020576    |   4:19:14 AM  |   1   |   4   |   25  |   2019    |   1

So now I have an indicator telling me if the previous record occurred on the same day as the current one. Now I want to calculate the difference in time from the previous record to the current one if they occurred on the same day. I use the following SQL and get an error.

```
SELECT   
EQUIPMENTNUMBER,   
[TimeOfDay],   
Month,  
WeekNumber,  
Day,    
Year,  
CASE  
  WHEN Day = lag(day,1,0) over (order by CEID, YEAR, WeekNumber, DAY,timeofday)   
THEN
    datediff(minute, lag(timeofday,1,0) over (order by CEID, YEAR, WeekNumber, DAY,timeofday), timeofday)
    ELSE 0 
END 
FROM [Table]
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 26
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with time
```

Can anyone out there please elaborate on what this error means or provide suggestions on how to calculate the difference in a timestamp between subsequent records in SQL Server?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post DDL for your table in a script that also populates that table with sample data. Why? Because your code references a column not represented in your formatted text. You also make a (perhaps big) assumption - that there will never be a day gap of one entire week. And that raises the question of why you choose to store the individual date components in separate columns.

Comment: And you should probably change your lag order to [year, month, day, time] - using week (rather than month) is more likely to cause problems. Well, depending on your definition of "same day" I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lag(timeofday,1,0) is the part that causing type clash.
timeofday is of type time and specified default for lag function is an int. these should be the same. either remove optional default or change to time type '00:00:00.000'

LAG (scalar_expression [,offset] [,default])
    OVER ( [ partition_by_clause ] order_by_clause )